# A Python implementation of GitHub flavored markdown

Tags: python, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I've been searching for a while now but still can't find anything. I basically need a Python converter for Github flavored markdown, that supports syntax highlighting. I currently use [gfm](https://github.com/stewart/gfm), however, that doesn't seem to support syntax highlighting. Not only it doesn't color it, it also does weird things with the code and puts it all on one line.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

There is another implementation of `gfm` for python: `py-gfm`:

http://pythonhosted.org/py-gfm/

It provides an extension for the `markdown` module:
https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/

Use it like this:

````
from markdown import Markdown
from mdx_gfm import GithubFlavoredMarkdownExtension

# extensions is a list, even if it's just one
md = Markdown(extensions=[GithubFlavoredMarkdownExtension()])

source = '''```python
print('Hello World')
```'''

html = md.convert(source)
````

Another possibility would be to use a javascript library like http://prismjs.com/, this would work also with `gfm` if this issue gets fixed:
https://github.com/stewart/gfm/issues/3

Comment: I'm trying to use this. Do you know of a way to include python variables being evaluated inside the markdown? Similar to how you have `print("This is {myvar}")`

Answer (score -1):

A simple and efficient alternative is [grip](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip).

Syntax highlithing is not handled, however.